# Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code in MongoDB v 4.2

Tags: mongodb, centos7

At first when I install MongoD using guidelines in official website link
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/ it is working fine.

When I alter the option bind_Ip to allow remote access or open firewall port 27017 or I wonder is there any other issue I get this error Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code                                                                                                                                                             . See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor prese                                                                                                                                                             t: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-06-27 19:51:57 BST; 10s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 2803 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=48)
Process: 2801 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited,                                                                                                                                                              status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 2798 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code                                                                                                                                                             =exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 2797 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, st                                                                                                                                                             atus=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 2154 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

I could not resolve it and could not get proper results from existing forums.
Thanks in advance for solution

Comment: Review the server log.

Comment: Hi, issue has been resolved. Actually bind_IP: "127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.1" should look like this. It varies for each version of MongoDB. If you get error message code exited=48 represents error in bind_IP option only.